# Adding lightbox to php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, lightbox2

I run small website (php) and I decided to implement lightbox. How it works:

My first document is main for all pages - clear.html, where I added:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" />` into head
and `<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>` into bottom above `</body>`.

My index.php loads parts of clear documents by `$sth->add(part_of_html)`. So if you want to load specific page, by clicking something in menu `$sth->` loads page (exercise.php) you requested into 'content'.

In exercise.php is code for image:

```
$s->change("image", '<br /><a href="/folder/'.$write["image"].'" data-lightbox="Image[exercise]" title="Hello"><img src="/folder/'.$write["Image"].'" alt="Hello" /></a><br />');
```

And finaly in exercise.html for exercise.php I want to use lightbox, there's an `[-image-]` box in `exercise.html`.

Final structure:

Index.php loads parts of clear.html (with lightbox.css sheet and script lightbox.js)
Index.php also loads exercise.php; which loads exercise.html AND replaces [-image-] in exercise.html with `<br /><a href="/folder/image1" data-lightbox="ImageExercise1" title="Hello"><img src="/folder/image1" alt="Hello" /></a><br />`

So everything should be ok. But if I click on image, it shows itself on same page, but on the left side (as if css would not work). 
When I tried it without [-image-], it has worked. But then you can not use `'.$write["image"].'` and it must be used. So code for getting images must be in php, because there are many different ones.

Why it acts like there's no css used, even if I declared it in clear.html? Is necessary to implement it to php too? I don't think so, when I had similar structure index.php loads ex.php and clear.html (with implementations) and ex.php loads ex.html, where are image tags?

Comment: Do you load jQuery [as they state](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started) ? *«... make sure it is loaded before lightbox.js. jQuery 1.7 or greater is required.»*

Comment: Yeah I did. I also tried to use their lightbox-plus-jquery file. I think js work. Problems are with css (I have an older website save on beta.page where I implemented successfully, but It seems It devil-knows-why css ignores

Comment: Anything in console ?

Comment: Iam so sorry I've just solved it. Problem was with internet cache. I reimplemented lightbox (there was an old one which didn't work) and pc browser remembered old lightbox.css file. I got this idea so I ran cCleaner and now it works. Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Yeah... Two things to check absolutely prior to post a question here (in order to make a better question) are: Check the console [F12] and empty the cache... ;)

Comment: Sorry Iam so new in this, I run this website 1 month (i got this) and all I knew before was that php has <? and ?> :D Iam learning quickly, though, but still I am so newbie. I found this cache cleaning only by chance so I forgot to use it (my beta web page doesn't need it somehow and firstly I made it there... so I didn't think about it firstly :( )